# Error using OAuth2 to connect to dropbox in Python

Tags: python-2.7, oauth, raspberry-pi, dropbox, dropbox-api

On my Raspberry Pi running raspbian jessie I tried to go through the OAuth2 flow to connect a program to my dropbox using the dropbox SDK for Python which I installed via pip.

For a test, I copied the code from the [documentation](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.org/en/master/moduledoc.html#module-dropbox.oauth) (and defined the app-key and secret, of course):

```
from dropbox import DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect

auth_flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)

authorize_url = auth_flow.start()
print "1. Go to: " + authorize_url
print "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)."
print "3. Copy the authorization code."
auth_code = raw_input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

try:
    access_token, user_id = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
except Exception, e:
    print('Error: %s' % (e,))
    return

dbx = Dropbox(access_token)
```

I was able to get the URL and to click allow. When I then entered the authorization code however, it printed the following error:

```
Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Using format_exc from the traceback-module, I got the following information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    access_token, user_id = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/oauth.py", line 180, in finish
    return self._finish(code, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/oauth.py", line 50, in _finish
    url = self.build_url(Dropbox.HOST_API, '/oauth2/token')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/oauth.py", line 111, in build_url
    return "https://%s%s" % (self._host, self.build_path(target, params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/oauth.py", line 89, in build_path
    params = params.copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

It seems the build_path method expects a dict 'params' and receives a string instead. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of the library are you using? See https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/issues/31... this should be fixed in 3.42.

Comment: Thank you! I have 3.41. So I will wait until 3.42 is available.

Comment: What do you mean "wait until 3.42 is available?" That's the current version on PyPI.

Comment: I git-cloned it after your comment and it was 3.41? I'll give it a try again tomorrow.

Comment: Huh. PyPI definitely has 3.42, but it does look like maybe that's not on GitHub. I'll look into it.

Comment: Yep, just tried via PyPI and I have 3.42 now. Unfortunately, I get a "HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token" in the new version when running the example-code...

Comment: I can't reproduce that error using your code above. (I had to add `Dropbox` to the import, and I dropped the `return` since I didn't have this in a function. Otherwise all I did was fill in an app key and secret.) Maybe start a new thread?

Comment: I'll give it one more try and open a new thread if it doesn't work. Thanks for your effort once again!

Comment: The new thread is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858793/httperror-finishing-the-oauth2-flow-with-dropbox-sdk-v-3-42-for-python).

Comment: FYI, GitHub now has 3.42.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [smarx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94559/smarx) for his comment. The error is a known issue and will be fixed in version 3.42 of the SDK. [source](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/issues/31)

Comment: Correction: *was* fixed in 3.42. :-)