# HTTPError finishing the OAuth2 flow with Dropbox SDK v 3.42 for Python

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, raspberry-pi, dropbox, dropbox-api

In SDK version 3.41 there was a bug that prevented the finish method of DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect to actually finish. I asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843613/error-using-oauth2-to-connect-to-dropbox-in-python) yesterday. After I updated to version 3.42, I get a new error. I once again took the code from the [Dropbox-documentation](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.org/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.oauth.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect) and changed it to the following to get a traceback and to be able to execute it outside of a function:

```
# added traceback-import
from traceback import format_exc

from dropbox import DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect

# replaced real key and secret by XXX
APP_KEY = "XXX"
APP_SECRET = "XXX"

auth_flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)

authorize_url = auth_flow.start()
print "1. Go to: " + authorize_url
print "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)."
print "3. Copy the authorization code."
auth_code = raw_input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

try:
    access_token, user_id = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
except:
    # changed output and removed return
    print format_exc()
else:
    print user_id, access_token
```

Running this gives me the following output after entering the authorization code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    access_token, user_id = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/oauth.py", line 178, in finish
    return self._finish(code, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/oauth.py", line 60, in _finish
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 837, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token
```

Where could I have made a mistake? Or is it a problem with the SDK?

Comment: Could it be that you're entering an invalid authorization code?

Comment: Or perhaps the app secret is invalid?

Comment: Seems that indeed something was wrong with the app secret. I didn't miss-spell it (copy & paste plus checked it a hundred times) but when I just deleted and re-created my Dropbox app, the error was gone. You saved my day :-)